# Django Celery receiving and accepting tasks, but not executing them

Tags: django, redis, celery, ubuntu-16.04, django-celery

I'm running a Django 1.11 (built using Cookiecutter-Django template) server on Digital Ocean running Ubuntu 16.04, Gunicorn, Nginx, and am trying to set up Celery tasks using Redis. The service seems to work and receive periodic tasks fine when I do:

```
celery -A config worker -B -l debug
```

And the tasks are received and accepted, but they don't execute. To test, I'm sending this function:

```
@shared_task(name="sum_two_numbers")
def add(x, y, **kwargs):
    return x + y
```

with:

```
add.delay(1,3)
```

And this is the complete printout of the console that Celery is running on:

```
 -------------- celery@myproject v4.1.0 (latentcall)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-112-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 2018-02-19 23:18:12
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         myproject:0x7f2cd60dc9e8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . . .
  . sum_two_numbers

[2018-02-19 23:18:12,858: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
[2018-02-19 23:18:12,876: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-02-19 23:18:13,910: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-02-19 23:18:13,924: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/user/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:202: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
[2018-02-19 23:19:38,714: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: sum_two_numbers[ab5b5547-1337-4dec-8848-c15e1a194b51]
[2018-02-19 23:19:38,715: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function _fast_trace_task at 0x7f2cd5fce510> (args:('sum_two_numbers', 'ab5b5547-1337-4dec-8848-c15e1a194b51', {'root_id': 'ab5b5547-1337-4dec-8848-c15e1a194b51', 'task': 'sum_two_numbers', 'group': None, 'correlation_id': 'ab5b5547-1337-4dec-8848-c15e1a194b51', 'id': 'ab5b5547-1337-4dec-8848-c15e1a194b51', 'timelimit': [None, None], 'expires': None, 'retries': 0, 'argsrepr': '(1, 3)', 'eta': None, 'origin': 'gen23535@myproject', 'reply_to': 'e67c54ef-3c66-3720-9e1f-62ef3d76882d', 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'lang': 'py', 'parent_id': None, 'delivery_info': {'priority': 0, 'redelivered': None, 'routing_key': 'celery', 'exchange': ''}}, b'[[1, 3], {}, {"errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null, "callbacks": null}]', 'application/json', 'utf-8') kwargs:{})
[2018-02-19 23:19:38,722: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: sum_two_numbers[ab5b5547-1337-4dec-8848-c15e1a194b51] pid:23512
```

When I run locally, it works just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: logs shows that task run successfully.

Comment: Not quite, when running it on my local machine, I also get this: `[2018-02-20 00:40:09,626: INFO/MainProcess] Task sum_two_numbers[f5d2d8b6-ebc6-492c-9b34-4c73fd46e134] succeeded in 0.0s: 4`

Comment: `Task sum_two_numbers[f5d2d8b6-ebc6-492c-9b34-4c73fd46e134] succeeded in 0.0s:` this show that it run successfully!

Comment: When you call `add.delay(1,3)` again then you will see the same log again which means that task run.

Comment: task is running successfully add a print statemetn to check proper result

Comment: Alright so I added `print('this is the result: ', x + y)` into the add equation and I'm getting the print statement in debug mode as `[2018-02-20 10:31:24,464: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] this is the result:
[2018-02-20 10:31:24,464: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 3
` But still the `succeeded` message doesn't appear in the remote machine, only on my local machine, which is the issue.

Answer (score 16):

You can try with this command -

```
celery -A <App_name> worker -l info --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair --pool=solo
```

This solved m issue by pooling in the solo mood. Maybe this is your case as well.

Comment: @takundamadechangu great to hear that

Comment: It worked for me too, but... What exactly does it do?

Comment: Please explain why. Yes, this command works, but need to know why does it work?

Comment: Please refer the wiki mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68061011/14202432. It seems when running on windows we should use like - celery -A <App_name> worker -l info --pool=solo (add --pool=solo at the end)